# Python Help - Ignore if file contains string from Whitelist

Tags: python

Python Noob <<

I've been piecing together code for a project.  I have code that can scan a file and then save the file if a keyword is matched.

But I'm getting too much stuff.  I now need a whitelist.

So basically, save the file if the keyword is matched (just like the code does), but then after matching, check to see if it contains any words from a (not yet created) whitelist keyword list.  If so, either delete the file, or just don't save it in the first place.

Can anyone help with adding that secondary check to scan against words from a new file?

```
# Run text against keyword list and save matches

keywords = [line.strip() for line in open(
    op.join(dir, 'keywords.txt'), 'r')
]
hits = []
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword.lower() in document_text.lower():
        hits.append(keyword)


# If there are matches, save to system
if hits:
    if _verbose:
        print 'INFO: Keyword Hit ' + document_id + ' ' + ','.join(hits)
    year = datetime.now().strftime('%Y')
    month = datetime.now().strftime('%m')
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%d')
    yyyymmdd = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')

    if not op.exists(op.join(dir, 'directory')):
        os.makedirs(op.join(dir, 'directory'))
    os.chdir(op.join(dir, 'directory'))
    if not op.exists(op.join(year, month, date)):
        os.makedirs(op.join(year, month, date))

    os.chdir(op.join(year, month, date))
    fname = yyyymmdd + '_' + document_id
    for hit in hits:
        fname += '_' + ''.join(ch for ch in hit if ch.isalnum())
    fname += '.txt'
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Title: ' + document_title + '\n')
        f.write(document_text)
```

Comment: which file are the words coming from?

Comment: Sounds like a blacklist, in which case you should first check that the document contains no words from that blacklist. Then, if it doesn't, do the `keywords` loop and proceed. If it does, `continue` or `return` or whatever you do to skip to the next file.